# Having trouble initializing array in Ada

Tags: arrays, binary-tree, ada

I'm in the early stages of learning Ada and using it to generate all distinct binary trees with n nodes. In doing so I've gotten stuck trying to initialize an array to store the tree instances that are returned back.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Program is

  function Factorial(N : in Positive) return Positive is
     Answer : Positive := 1;
  begin
     if N > 1 then
       Answer := N * Factorial(N - 1);
     end if;
     return Answer;
   end Factorial;

  --TreeNode Declaration
  type Tree_Node;
  type Tree_Ptr is access Tree_Node;

  --TreeNode Definition
  type Tree_Node is
    record
      Left : Tree_Ptr;
      Right: Tree_Ptr;
    end record;

  type TreeList is array (Integer range <>) of Tree_Ptr;

  function RecDistinctTree(Start : in Positive; Finish : in Positive; ArraySize : in Positive) return TreeList is
     RetList : TreeList(0..ArraySize);
  begin
     if Start > Finish then
        return RetList;
     else
           for I in Start..Finish loop
                declare
                  LeftChild : TreeList;
                  RightChild : TreeList;
                begin
                  LeftChild := RecDistinctTree(Start, I - 1);
                  RightChild := RecDistinctTree(I + 1, Finish);

                  for J in LeftChild'Range loop
                      declare
                        LeftNode : Tree_Ptr;
                      begin
                        LeftNode := LeftChild(J);
                        for K in RightChild'Range loop
                            declare
                              RightNode : Tree_Ptr;
                              NewNode : Tree_Node;
                            begin
                              NewNode.Left := LeftNode;
                              NewNode.Right := RightNode;

                              -- Make functions for adding to list
                            end;
                        end loop;
                      end;
                  end loop;
                end;
           end loop;
     end if;
  end;
  ArraySize : Integer;
  N : Integer;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Enter # of nodes");
   N := Integer'Value(Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line);
   ArraySize :=  (Factorial(2*N) / (Factorial(N+1) * Factorial(N)));
  declare
     TreeArray : TreeList;
   begin
     for I in 0..(ArraySize-1) Loop
       Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Node!");
     end Loop;
   end;
end Program;
```

The program is not complete, I'm just trying to understand how to initialize the 'RetList' in the RecDistinctTree function. Currently when it compiles, I get the errors:

program.adb:35:31: unconstrained subtype not allowed (need initialization)

program.adb:35:31: provide initial value or explicit array bounds

I've dug around looking for answers, but not much exists for Ada compared to more popular languages. Why does it not simply instantiate the array of ArraySize # of Tree_Ptr's? Perhaps I don't fully grasp subtypes.

Comment: Why do you think the compiler should create an array of size ArraySize? rather than e.g. ArraySize - 1? or 42?

Comment: In this case, the size of the array returned is the amount of possible binary search trees, given n nodes. I can anticipate this value with 2n! / ((n+1)! * n!) so that I never overallocate.

Comment: What is the point of type Tree_Node? It contains left and right pointers but does not contain any integer data? TreeList is an unconstrained array of Tree_Node. The Left and Right pointers of Tree_Node will contain the default value of Null, and cannot reference array elements in TreeList. Your implementation appears to be an unworkable mixture of an array implementation of a tree and a binary tree using pointers.

Comment: In my case, I'm not storing data. My task is to enumerate all possible binary trees with n-nodes. For this, I need no data.

Answer (score 4):

The type `TreeList` is indefinite as the index range has been left unconstrained in the type declaration:

```
type TreeList is array (Integer range <>) of Tree_Ptr;
```

Therefore, when declaring a variable of type `TreeList`, you must either provide array bounds to constrain index range of the array (as you did for the first `RetList` declaration):

```
RetList : TreeList (0 .. ArraySize);   -- This is OK (note that the length of this array will be ArraySize + 1)
```

Or initialize it (e.g. using a function) such that the compiler can infer the index range from the value being assigned. Maybe you could try something like:

```
declare
  --  ??? Third argument is missing in example.
  LeftChild  : TreeList := RecDistinctTree (Start, I - 1, ???);  
  RightChild : TreeList := RecDistinctTree (I + 1, Finish, ???);
begin
  [...]
```